# How do I test my racket quickcheck generator?

Tags: racket, quickcheck

Lets say I have a generator for interval structs e.g.

```
(struct interval (lo hi)
      #:methods gen:custom-write
    [(define write-proc
       (make-constructor-style-printer
        (lambda (obj) 'interval)
        (lambda (obj) (list (interval-hi obj) (interval-lo obj)))))])

(define (choose-interval [min-value -100] [max-value 100])
  (bind-generators
   ([lo (choose-real min-value max-value)]
    [hi (choose-real lo max-value)])
   (interval lo hi)))
```

According to the docs generator has a member called [proc](https://docs.racket-lang.org/quickcheck/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._quickcheck%2Fmain..rkt%29._generator%29%29) that takes a test size argument and a random number generator. But where do I get this random number generator? The [make-random-generator](https://docs.racket-lang.org/quickcheck/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._quickcheck%2Fmain..rkt%29._make-random-generator%29%29) symbol in the docs is not actually exported by the module!

How do i get some values out of this generator so I can be sure it is working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make-random-generator` should be exported. See [This PR](https://github.com/ifigueroap/racket-quickcheck/pull/41).

Comment: Good luck with the PR!

Comment: @FrankWilson or maybe you could try out [rackcheck](https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackcheck/index.html). It seems much better maintained, supports shrinking, and has very consistent APIs.